# Git how to find out what is current tag for specific branch

Tags: git, version-control, tags, branch

Let's say we have **100 commits** and it includes **10 branches** and **5 tags**.

Every tag describes some kind of history of these **100 commits** (shortly release).

Question is how we can get list of tags or just simple last tag for specific branch?

Let's say we would like to know what **branch-5** is currently pointing on? Is it **tag-1, tag-2, tag-n**?

Please is there any simple way how to achieve this?

Comment: Please note that in git, a branch does not describe a group of commits, but a singular label for _one_ of them.

Comment: Short answer is [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)

Comment: If you're sure there're tags at the tip of the branch the command is `git tag --points-at branch-5`

Comment: Many thanks guys. It worked well. I used shortest one cmd with git describe <branch-5> and it worked well. Just one tip. If an branch does not exist then it fails and can be handled like this. git describe <branch-5> 2> null || echo please check and choose proper branch